# Fine-tuning Markov chain

Tags: r, markov-chains

I have the following Markov chain:

```
pre<-cbind(c(rep("rain",100),rep("sun",100),rep("rain",100)))
post<-cbind(c(rep("rain",50),rep("sun",70),rep("rain",100),rep("sun",80)))
df<-cbind(pre,post)
df<-as.data.frame(df)
colnames(df)<-c("pre","post")

states<-c("rain","sun")

probsCase<-function(i,j){
sum(as.character(df$pre)==states[i] & as.character(df$post)==states[j])/sum(as.character(df$pre)==states[i])
}

transitionMatrix<-outer(1:2,1:2,Vectorize(probsCase))
colnames(transitionMatrix)<-states
rownames(transitionMatrix)<-states

library(diagram)
plotmat(transitionMatrix,relsize=0.75)
```

which results in the following plot:

[image]

How can I rotate it 90 degrees clockwise, and adjust the self-directed circular arrows so that they are on the midline axis of the plot, opposite from each other instead of being partially on the side as they currently are?

Answer (score 0):

the circular arrows can be changed by manipulating `self.shiftx` and `self.shifty` values. The arrow location on the circle is determined by `self.arrpos` but, beware, the angles is measured in radians, not degrees. The box labels can be switched by altering the sequence of the states like this: `states<-c("sun","rain")` instead of `states<-c("rain","sun")`.  Still trying to figure out how to rotate the entire plot by 90 degrees.